# Wordpress login not works on other pages

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have problems with log in on my wordpress website.
There is a pop up window contains log in form.
The form works fine, but in other pages I should refresh the page to recognize that user is logged in or not. 
Can you help me?
Here is my website : www.pingdvr.com

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine to be honest, if you are viewing pages before you logged in then yes you are going to need to refresh.

Please let us know more :)

Comment: The pages not restricted.
For now I want to change log in button text to " Log out "
It works in each page that user loges in . but in other pages it require refresh the page.